# Sencha Touch - how to re-initialize a map view from a controller

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, leaflet

I would like to re-initialize my map view after a certain action performed in the controller.

This is my mapview:

```
Ext.define("App.view.MapView", {
extend: 'Ext.Container',
requires: [
    'Ext.device.Geolocation',
    'Ext.MessageBox'
],
xtype: 'mapview',

constructor: function () {
    this.callParent(arguments);
    this.element.setVisibilityMode(Ext.Element.OFFSETS);
    this.on('painted', this.renderMap, this);
},

renderMap: function(){
        var me = this,
            lat = localStorage.getItem('latitude'),
            lng = localStorage.getItem('longitude'), 
            geo = [lat, lng];

        var map = L.map('map', {
            center: geo, 
            zoom: 13
        });

        var layer = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }).addTo(map);    

        var marker = L.marker(geo, {
            draggable: true,
            title: 'Your position'
        }).addTo(map);
}
});
```

How do I get and reset(re-initialize) my map view? I tried to make a reference to the mapview in the controller:

```
config: {
    refs: {
        mapCmp: 'mapview',
    },
```

And then called it like this:

```
this.getApplication().getMapCmp.reset();
```

But it didn't work - I got 'function is undefined'. Basically I need it to initialize again like when the app starts up.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get *function is undefined* message because the `reset()` function is not defined in your view.

However, if you want to initialize the MapView, you need to use the `initialize()` function. Add it in your file:

```
Ext.define("App.view.MapView", {
extend: 'Ext.Container',
requires: [
    'Ext.device.Geolocation',
    'Ext.MessageBox'
],
xtype: 'mapview',

constructor: function () {
    this.callParent(arguments);
    this.element.setVisibilityMode(Ext.Element.OFFSETS);
    this.on('painted', this.renderMap, this);
},

initialize: function() {
    // This function is launched each time the application starts up
}

renderMap: function(){
        var me = this,
            lat = localStorage.getItem('latitude'),
            lng = localStorage.getItem('longitude'), 
            geo = [lat, lng];

        var map = L.map('map', {
            center: geo, 
            zoom: 13
        });

        var layer = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }).addTo(map);    

        var marker = L.marker(geo, {
            draggable: true,
            title: 'Your position'
        }).addTo(map);
},
});
```